# Flash: Reveil/fade in parts of a picture?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

How do I make certain parts of a picture fade in, in the movie?

an example would be showing script as it is written (i.e. it reveals more and more of the script as it fades in.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest for you will be to animate the mask layer

http://www.gomediazine.com/tutorials/an-angel-grows-wings-animated-mask-in-flash/

but if you want to do text over time, you might need to script it.

for this type of stuff, if you do go the scripting way, hype is a great library that makes it easy

http://www.hypeframework.org/

Comment: np, do give the hype framework a try when you get a bit more comfortable with as3, it's a lot of fun (or at least look at some of the demos)